# Mini game within a game

Tags: mechanics

Are there any board games where you play a mini game within the main game?

For example, imagine playing *Axis & Allies* where you play a quick game of *Tic-Tac-Toe* each round to see which side gets a free submarine.

Comment: [Enter the Dungeon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74312) not only has you play a Magic subgame but you play it *under the table*. (I suppose there was also [Shahrazad](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shahrazad), but that's clearly not as cool.)

Comment: Also, if what you're actually looking for is to learn how a mechanic like this might be used (and how well it works), you might want to edit your question. As it is, you're kind of polling (asking for a list of many games), as evidenced by the answers, which is a valid reason to close questions, since we like directly answerable questions.

Comment: This is a poll question, where [every answer is equally valid](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). As Jefromi says, it encourages many answers, each listing one example of the mechanic. Think about what you really want to know, and try and reword the question so that a single answer could give you that. In other words, focus on the motivation for asking for the list. I'm closing this for now to prevent more of the same answers. Feel free to flag for reopening after you've adjusted the question.

Comment: Actually, the only answers I expected were "Yes" and "No", instead of examples.  Since people answered with examples, I'm fine with leaving this one closed.

Answer (score 1):

[Trajan](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/102680/trajan) has you playing a round of [Mancala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mancala) each turn to decide what action you take, with bonuses for accumulating the correct colored pieces in certain locations.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mansions of Madness has a number of 'puzzles' that are like mini-games. You have to solve them to uncover clues and gather other important things.

[image: Mansions of Madness Puzzle setup example page]

Answer (score 0):

The [Shahrazad card](http://magiccards.info/an/en/67.html) in Magic the Gathering has the players stop playing the game and play another game of Magic with their remaining cards.

[image]

Comment: A very controversial card, given that its main function seems to be for building decks that can spin out the length of a game of Magic long enough to guarantee a draw under tournament conditions...

Answer (score 0):

If you play [Gipf](http://www.gipf.com/) with [potentials](http://www.gipf.com/project_gipf/index.html) then each time you activate a potential you play the game the potential if based on. If you win you are allowed to use the potential power.

Note that these rules are optional (for one you would need to own the game, and it also takes a long time if you play with many potential). Also, while each game is played on its own all of them are full games, worth playin gin their own right.